# JSP can send file to AWS bucket using static source file address in the code, but doesn't work dynamically

Tags: java, jsp, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, form-submit

I have following line in my code to send file to AWS cloud.

```
s3Client.putObject(new PutObjectRequest(bucket, fileName, 
                new File("/Users/MyFolder/Desktop/Test/logo.jpg")).withCannedAcl(CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead));          
    }
```

I have following line in my HTML code to point to the source file.

```
<tr>
        <td><b>Select a Logo:</b></td>
        <td><INPUT NAME="file" TYPE="file"></td>
</tr>
```

When the html code is send by clicking send button, It should send the file to my JSP page, that I can use instead of

```
"/Users/MyFolder/Desktop/Test/logo.jpg"
```

in my code.

I know it can be done using creating a blank object in my AWS cloud, sending bytes to the newly created file, and changing its file extension with metadata. Just can't stream it correctly.
Getting a bunch of errors when trying to replace the static path.

Here is the screenshot of the code. Hope it might help.

[image]

Comment: How are you trying to do it?

Comment: I have created empty object with InputStream and then uploaded that object in my AWS bucket with PutObjectRequest using s3Client.
putObject(putObjectRequest). and then I don't know how to upload the file that i am sending via HTML form.

Comment: Well if you're not going to show the code that doesn't work, then I guess I can't say why it doesn't work.

Comment: ohh....you want to see the code. Sorry bro. Give me a minute. let me start eclipse and give you the code. Actually I have used my complete code upload in stackoverflow and i was told not to do that. will be back in a sec. Thanks

Comment: Hi immibis, I have just updated the question with the screenshot of the code. I asked someone to send me the screenshot because I am at work and can't access it from here. Hope it will help you to understand it. Thanks a lot.